# jQuery activate (bind) scroll after unbind

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am firing an event when I scroll to the bottom of the page, but I don't want it to fire more than once in a 2 second period.

I've used `$(window).unbind('scroll');` to unbind it so it doesn't fire more than once.  How can I "rebind" or "bind" it so that the scroll function can be active again after 2 seconds?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();     
    win_height = $(window).height();        
    doc_height = $(document).height();      

    if(scroll_pos + win_height > doc_height - 100) {

        $('#gifLoad').show();
        $(window).unbind('scroll');

        setTimeout(function(){

            $('#gifLoad').hide();
            //$(window).bind('scroll');     //<--- this doesn't work..

        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify what to bind the second time you're calling `$(window).bind`

```
function onScroll() {
    scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();     
    win_height = $(window).height();        
    doc_height = $(document).height();      

    if(scroll_pos + win_height > doc_height - 100) {

        $('#gifLoad').show();
        $(window).unbind('scroll');

        setTimeout(function(){    
            $('#gifLoad').hide();
            $(window).bind('scroll', onScroll);    
        }, 2000);
    }
}
$(window).scroll(onScroll);
```

Or you could set a flag to ignore events for two seconds

```
// You can wrap all this in a self calling anonymous function  to avoid a global;
var ignoreScroll = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (ignoreScroll) return;


    scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();     
    win_height = $(window).height();        
    doc_height = $(document).height();      

    if(scroll_pos + win_height > doc_height - 100) {

        $('#gifLoad').show();

        ignoreScroll = true;

        setTimeout(function(){
            ignoreScroll = false;
            $('#gifLoad').hide();
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to (re-)bind the event, you need to pass a handler function. jQuery doesn't magically know that you want to re-bind the previously removed `scroll` event handler just because you've not passed anything.

There are two ways to achieve what you want to do. You've asked about re-binding the event, so let's cover that first. You'll need a named, rather than anonymous, function, then you just pass a reference to that when calling `.bind()` in your setTimeout:

```
function handleScroll() {

    scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();     
    win_height = $(window).height();        
    doc_height = $(document).height();      

    if(scroll_pos + win_height > doc_height - 100) {

        $('#gifLoad').show();
        $(window).unbind('scroll');

        setTimeout(function(){

            $('#gifLoad').hide();
            $(window).bind('scroll', handleScroll); // bind to call the same function again

        }, 2000);
    }
}

$(window).scroll(handleScroll);
```

The second method, which should be more efficient since you don't need to keep removing and adding event handlers, is to use a boolean flag to determine if you actually run that extra bit of logic:

```
var runScrollLogic = true;

$(window).scroll(function() {

    scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();     
    win_height = $(window).height();        
    doc_height = $(document).height();      

    if(scroll_pos + win_height > doc_height - 100 && runScrollLogic === true) {

        $('#gifLoad').show();
        runScrollLogic = false; // disables execution of this part

        setTimeout(function(){

            $('#gifLoad').hide();
            runScrollLogic = true; // enables execution again

        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, we posted pretty much the same two solutions

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use the current time and the time the event was fired last.

```
var lastScrollTime = null;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();

    if ((lastScrollTime == null) || ((currentTime - lastScroll) >= 2000)) {
        scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();     
        win_height = $(window).height();        
        doc_height = $(document).height();      

        if(scroll_pos + win_height > doc_height - 100) {
            $('#gifLoad').show();
        }

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#gifLoad').hide();
        }, 2000);

        lastScrollTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    }
});
```

Comment: Now I think we've listed all three possible solutions ;)

Comment: @JuanMendes: Heh heh... well, since he is only showing the gif for 2 seconds, he could also only fire the `show()` on the condition that it's not already showing like `if (!$('#gifLoad').is(":visible")) {`